# Does iPhone's baseband change when updating iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, unlock

I would like to know more about basebands.

- Does it change when updating iOS?
- Do all iPhones have the same baseband?
- If not, how do they differ?
- And ... can I unlock an iPhone 4 with iOS 5.1.1?

I would be very grateful for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

### Q: Does it change when updating iOS?

A: Yes, the firmware is revised and is packaged inside the software update archive.

### Q: Do all iPhones have the same baseband?

A: No. They get updated and iPhones can have one of multiple chips with incompatible firmware.

### Q: If not, how do they differ?

A: Bugfixes, security patches etc. Different generations have differing chipsets as well.

### Q: And ... can I unlock an iPhone 4 with iOS 5.1.1?

A: [Yes](http://www.engadget.com/2012/06/04/ultrasn0w-unlock-iphone-4-3gs-ios-5-1-1/), you can use ultrasn0w for a software unlock if your iPhone 4's baseband is 01.59.00. You can check your baseband version by going to `Settings`->`General`->`About` and looking at the `Modem Firmware` number.

Sources:

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Category:Baseband

http://www.engadget.com/2012/06/04/ultrasn0w-unlock-iphone-4-3gs-ios-5-1-1/

iPhone 4 Chipset Page: http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=XMM_6180